# IS_ERR() macro in Linux

Tags: c, linux, macros, linux-device-driver

While getting to know how to write device drivers I came across IS_ERR() macro. But I couldn't find how is it working. I have include the code below:

```
majorNumber = register_chrdev(0, DEVICE_NAME, &fops);

if (majorNumber<0)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Failed to register a major number\n");
    return majorNumber;
}
printk(KERN_INFO "Registered correctly with major number %d\n", majorNumber);

// Register the device class
ebbcharClass = class_create(THIS_MODULE, CLASS_NAME);

if (IS_ERR(ebbcharClass))
{               
  unregister_chrdev(majorNumber, DEVICE_NAME);
  printk(KERN_ALERT "Failed to register device class\n");
  return PTR_ERR(ebbcharClass);          
}
```

So what does the IS_ERR() macro expand to and how it gets executed.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. If you only wish to see what the macro evaluates to, compile with `-E` option

Comment: I have edited my question to give a clear meaning of what I need to know.

Comment: Btw, use `pr_*()` macros for print and check the [CodingStyle](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle) just in case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tests if the supplied pointer should be considered an **error value**.

It does not check if the pointer is valid.

In your code IS_ERR is used to check if `class_create` succeded creating `ebbcharClass`. If an error occurs unregister the char driver and signal the error.

You can find MACROs and inline funcs in [`err.h`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/err.h#L34)

Comment: I would add that is defined in `err.h`.

Comment: I saw somewhere IS_ERR is used like this : if (IS_ERR(dev_ret = class_create(THIS_MODULE, "chardev"))) . so IS_ERR works both for the `return value of class_create function` and the `assignment operation of class_create return value`? from https://testkernel.tistory.com/91

Answer (score 8):

Be careful for pitfall:

```
#define IS_ERR_VALUE(x) unlikely((x) >= (unsigned long)-MAX_ERRNO)
#define MAX_ERRNO       4095
```

This covers -1 to -4095, which represents error code, not number below 4096, nor NULL (0).
Every value from 0 to 4294963201 (0xfffff001) is considered no error.
Do not use it to cover NULL checking.

Comment: Range typo: good value should be from 0 to 4294963200 (0xfffff000).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know what the macro expands to, just compile your file using the `-E` option of gcc, which will only do pre-processing. It will include all headers and expand all macros.

The macro does not "get executed" per se, it's just a "search and replace" type of thing.